# How to create a menu similar to the Windows 7 Start Menu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, desktop-application

I am contemplating having a menu in my WPF application that works in a similar way to the Windows 7 start menu.

In my mind, this means that I should make a user control that consitues a button. Clicking on the button will display a list box, and inside the list box it will be possible to search the items that are registered in the list box.

Would that be an advisable way of doing it or is it better to do something different such as changing the template of a menu control?

Thanks for any help, it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have the design already made up.  Do exactly that!  :)  Create a button that when pressed, displays a panel that contains a list box and a text box.  Tie an event to key presses in the text box that changes what the object bound to the list contains.

After that, it's just a [SMOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming)!